# what would be the appropriate word in this passage? possibly loosely related to "conflate"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, meaning-in-context

i'm looking for a word that means intentionally attempting to conflate/situate two apparently contradictory ideas/beliefs etc.- for example, "as a practicing psychiatrist, is it possible for me to ___ my feminist ideology with my chosen career?"

Comment: Did you mean kind of *juxtapose* ? But I suppose there's a much better word, let me see.

Comment: You almost certainly mean _reconcile_, given your example sentence. But it doesn't mean the same thing as _conflate_, which may be causing some confusion.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I am really wondering why modern psychiatry and feminism would be "apparently contradictory"... Surely (most) psychiatrists nowadays would not classify the wish for equal rights for all genders as a disease of the mind — or should I get me some pills?

Answer (score 4):

*[Blend](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blend)*, if you are looking for a slightly looser fit:

> 1.2 Put or combine (abstract things) together:
>
> *ODO*

*As a practicing psychiatrist, is it possible for me to **blend** my feminist ideology with my chosen career?*

Answer (score 3):

*[Fuse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fuse)*, if you really want to communicate them being melted together into one unit:

> verb
>
> 1 [WITH OBJECT] Join or blend to form a single entity:
>
> *ODO*

*[etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fuse&allowed_in_frame=0)*

> 1680s, "to melt, make liquid by heat" (transitive), back-formation
>   from fusion.
>   Intransitive sense, "to become liquid," attested from
>   1800.
>   Figurative sense of "blend different things, blend or unite as if by melting together" is recorded by 1817.
>   Intransitive figurative
>   sense "become intermingled or blended" is by 1873.

*As a practicing psychiatrist, is it possible for me to **fuse** my feminist ideology with my chosen career?*

Answer (score 2):

Or *[coalesce](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coalesce)* in a different construction:

> verb
>
> 1.0 [NO OBJECT] Come together to form one mass or whole:
>
> 1.1 [WITH OBJECT] Combine (elements) in a mass or whole:

*Is it possible for my feminist ideology and my psychiatric practice to **coalesce** in real life?*

Answer (score 1):

***reconcile***

***harmonize***

***compromise*** (to adjust or settle by partial mutual relinquishment of principles, position, or claims :  settle by coming to terms )

should all be possible.

Answer (score 1):

With required sentence :

> As a practicing psychiatrist, is it possible for me *to make coexist* my feminist ideology with my chosen career?

Coming from [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/coexist):

> **coexist** /ˌkəʊɪɡˈzɪst/ vb (intransitive)
>
> > to exist together at the same time or in the same place
> >
> > to exist together in peace

---

#### But the sentence is better as follow :

> As a practicing psychiatrist, is it possible for me that my feminist ideology and my chosen career **coexist**?

---

@aparente001 proposition :

> As a practicing psychiatrist, is it possible for my feminist ideology to **co-exist** with my chosen career?

Comment: nice idea, but the sentences you propose don't hang together well.  Here's a variant that works better in English: is it possible for my feminist ideology to co-exist with my chosen career?

Answer (score 0):

reconcile

integrate

That was not enough characters, so here's some filler.

Comment: Please explain your answer. don't just insert filler.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен I only had two words to propose.  - - - If you have a question or would like some more information about something, please let me know.  I just don't know what you'd like me to explain here.

Comment: What the words mean and how they suit the question.

Answer (score -1):

**cohere**

to be naturally or logically connected:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cohere

Comment: I do not think that word fits.

Comment: Good for you. Perhaps it will help lucille2. :)